# How do I translate Romaji to Kana?

Tags: keyboard-layout, language-support, input-language, japanese

I used Windows 10 before, and now switched to Ubuntu MATE 16.04. I got the Japanese input working quite nicely with Mozc. However, in Windows you could put in the Romaji and they would transit into Kana immediately, whereas in my case there is basically a keybinding for each symbol. I could get used to it, but it's not that convenient after all.

I would appreciate your help.

P.S. Sorry for the noobish style, I started using Ubuntu like a week ago.

Comment: What do you mean by "keybinding for each symbol"? Do you get the dropdown menu for the various options? There is no one-to-one translation between romaji and kana, the same romaji might be written in several ways.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto; Wow, I'm a real idiot. It's togglable in Mozc Tool -> Configuration Tool -> Input Method. Set that up to Romaji and everything seems to work like it used to. Anyway, you got my attention on the dropdowns, so thanks. Problem solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be toggled in Mozc Tool -> Configuration Tool -> Input Method. Set the method to Romaji and the latin characters will automatically transform into Kana, and ultimately, Kanji. Case closed.